# How can I modify the media upload form fields?

Tags: uploads, forms, media

I would like to add a line of text under the description field in the media edit form to give users more direction as to how to fill out this field. What is the best way to do this? I know how to add form fields, but can't seem to figure out how to modify existing ones.

I added

```
unset($form_fields['post_content']);
```

but for some reason this doesn't seem to remove the default description field.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Would maybe look into [`do_action( 'pre-upload-ui' );`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L1547).

Here is my first thoughts, please note it's not tested but should get you in the right direction.

```
add_action( 'pre-plupload-upload-ui', 'sd_extra_info' );

function sd_extra_info()
{
    # see wp-includes/media-template.php
    print '<pre> Some more info here </pre>';
}
```

Comment: Two notes: Aside from some minor exceptions, all filters and hooks use underscores `_` instead of dashes `-` for separation. Then there's the point that I can't find `pre_plupload_`, `pre-upload` or similar strings in the WordPress source. Are you sure about that?

Comment: @kaiser, I'm afraid [there is](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L1600) (I've searched for `-plupload-`, those hooks gotta be left overs of some party barbecue wpcamp:). stevie's code results in [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UFzH1.png)

Comment: @brasofilo thanks, mate :) wtf did the one who added that name drink? oh, and I used GitHub search on WordPress/WordPress mirror repo.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I used the wrong name for the field I'm trying to modify. I need to modify the description field when a user uploads media from the add new post page. See photo: http://imgur.com/nlAvSyR I've figured out how to add new fields here, but need to modify the existing description field. I added in a field with just help text, but can't make it not display a text input field. Also, I guess this field also appears in the edit media page after the media item is uploaded. Thanks again, sorry for not making that more clear.

Comment: I think I can do what I need by using the attachment_fields_to_edit hook and deleting the description field and then adding back a modified version of it. My problem is that unset($form_fields['post_content']); will not remove the field and I'm not sure why. ???

Comment: @SeanHenderson, you have to edit your Question to add this details, they don't belong in the Comments thread.